# #document in Object

Tags: php, html

I'm having a weird problem here, I execute following php script to then echo it in my HTML. The thing is, after the echo Object gets the following in it:

> ```
> \#document
> <html>...(body+head both empty)<?html>
> ```

my script

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $id = $row["id"];
    $youtube = $row["youtube"];
    $name = $row["title"];
    $votes = $row["votes"];
    $select .= "<div class='select' id='$id'>
                    <object data='http//img.youtube.com/vi/$youtube/0.jpg'></object>
                    <p>$name | Stemmen: $votes</p>
                </div>";

}
```

Comment: What ever is doing that isn't in the code you've shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your developer tools are showing you the content located at the *relative* URL `http//img.youtube.com/vi/$youtube/0.jpg` (which is a blank HTML document).

You are missing a `:` and should be using an `<img>` rather than an `<object>`.